# Notification sound delay when app is in quite state

Tags: react-native

Notification is received instantly but notification sound is played in delay(5 or 10 sec)
Here is my setbackgroundHandler and notification is sent using `node.js` and firebase post API, when the app is in background sound is play instantly but in quit/killed state sound is played after 5 or 10 sec(delayed)

```js
AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);

// Register  background handler
messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async (remoteMessage) => {
  console.log('Message handled in the background', remoteMessage);
  play();
});

const play = () => {
  var whoosh = new Sound('notfi.mp3', Sound.MAIN_BUNDLE, (error) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log('failed to load the sound', error);
      return;
    }
    // loaded successfully
    console.log(
      'duration in seconds: ' +
        whoosh.getDuration() +
        'number of channels: ' +
        whoosh.getNumberOfChannels()
    );

    // Play the sound with an onEnd callback
    whoosh.play((success) => {
      if (success) {
        console.log('successfully finished playing');
      } else {
        console.log('playback failed due to audio decoding errors');
      }
    });
  });
};

const notification_body = {
  notification: {
    title: notification.title,
    body: notification.description,
  },
  registration_ids: tokens,
};

return axios.post(`${process.env.FIREBASE_FCM_URL}`, notification_body, {
  headers: {
    Authorization: `key=${process.env.FIREBASE_SERVER_KEY}`,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
});
```